# Issues building Hibernate 4.1.2.final through gradle

Tags: hibernate, gradle, hibernate-envers

I am trying to patch hibernate due to [HHH-6960](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6960).  However, the following issue arrises when executing `gradle clean build`.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Work\Samples\hibernate-release-4.1.2.Final\project\documentation\documentation.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':documentation'.
> Could not find property 'buildDirName' on project ':documentation'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.502 secs
PS C:\Work\Samples\hibernate-release-4.1.2.Final\project\hibernate-envers>
```

This straight out of the box without any modifications... i simply downloaded hibernate and gradle and ran it.  I'm new to gradle so what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you downloaded hibernate AND gradle? You don't need to download gradle manually to run the hibernate build. 
Instead of using your local installation of gradle you should use the gradlewrapper (the gradlew / gradlew.bat script in the root of the hibernate sources) to build gradle.
does this solve your issues?

Comment: please review my comment to ctapobep's answere.

Comment: just a guess: is your JAVA_HOME pointing to a jre instead of a jdk? For further help, please provide the output of gradlew clean test -i

Comment: Had to install groovy which also added to groovy_home to env variables. I also added Java_home to env variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have with Gradle is the scripts are written using the version incompatible with the one you installed. Gradle is such a product that often looses backward compatibility because it's in active development.

You can either use gradlew scripts as the fastest solution, because they don't require you installing anything, or just take a look inside at those gradlew, they contain the version of Gradle these scripts require.

Comment: I downloaded hibernate-orm from github which has the wrapper and executed `gradlew clean test --stacktrace` with resulting error `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Forked groovyc returned error code: 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.`